# Rails download S3 file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sdk, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

I'm uploading files to S3 with paperclip, and now I would like to download them from the same app. So I'm doing what lots of pages says, but if I use 'aws-sdk' it says that AWS::S3::S3Object method 'find' doesn't exist, and If I use 'aws-s3' gem, it says that I need to use 'aws-sdk'. 
In controller I'm calling:

```
aws_object = AWS::S3::S3Object.find @component.folder.path, 'bucket-name'
send_data(aws_object.value, :type => @component.folder_content_type)
```

**EDIT:**
My model looks like:

```
attr_accessible :folder

has_attached_file   :folder, 
                    :path => ":rails_root/data/folders/:id/:basename.:extension",
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => {
                        :bucket => "my-bucket-name",
                        :access_key_id => "XXXXXXXXX",
                        :secret_access_key => "XXXXXXXXX"
                    }
```

Comment: What does your model look like?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

http://trevorturk.com/2008/12/11/easy-upload-via-url-with-paperclip/

There's a example to download too.

The secret was ".read" :

```
data = open(asset.uploaded_file.url)
send_data data.read, :type => data.content_type, :x_sendfile => true,:filename => asset.file_name
```